# Convert a NSTimeInterval duration into NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new in iphone development. I have a issue. I want to convert a NSTimeInterval value in NSString, but not success in this. please a quick look on below code.

in .h

```
NSTimeInterval startTime;
NSTimeInterval stopTime;
NSTimeInterval duration;
```

in .m

```
startTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
stopTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

duration = stopTime-startTime;

NSLog(@"Duration is %@",[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: duration]);
NSLog(@"Duration is %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", duration]);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

NSString *time = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:duration];----> Error
[dateFormatter release];
```

And on one label set this string----

```
[timeLabel setText:time];
```

but it not works it shows  error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'stringFromDate:'

and if i comment that line it shows the right duration in console window.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [NSDateFormatter class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
- (NSString *)stringFromDate:(NSDate *)date
                              ^^^^^^^^ the type of the argument
```

From your code:

```
NSTimeInterval duration; 
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the type of what you are passing.
```

The error says "incompatible type".  What do you think that means?  Perhaps NSTimeInterval is not compatible with NSDate*.  Here is what the docs say about [NSTimeInterval](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html):

```
typedef double NSTimeInterval;
```

> NSTimeInterval is always specified in seconds...

The error is telling you the compiler can't convert an NSTimeInterval (which is really a double) into a pointer to an NSDate.  This is not surprising really.  Since an NSTimeInterval is really a double, you can convert it into a string easily by using the `%f` format specifier.

```
foo = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", timeInterval];
```

Comment: Thanks All, for quick response. by u suggestions i have understand that i am going to pass a different argument type. Now its work fine.

Again Thanks Vladimir,Toro and JeremyP.

Comment: Really cool that you pointed out that the NSTimeInterval was a double, I needed the time in milliseconds, so I just multiplied it by 1000 and solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

NSTimeInterval is actually a double, so to convert it to a string you should just use

```
NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", duration];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *time = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:duration];----> Error
```

This duration is not class **NSDate**, so It can not be converted by this method named **stringFromDate**.
As Vladimir said, NSTimeInterval is double, with his method you can get the right NSString.